# Trimble Pathfinder Differential Correction: ‘Uncorrected’ for block of GPS data

Tags: gps, data-collection, pathfinder

I’ve been collecting GPS point data without problems over the last few months. Recently, on two dates, after using Pathfinder differential correction, the exported records’ Corr_Type changed from Postprocessed Code to Uncorrected. In other words, the records are Postprocessed Code (which is what I want to see) up to a certain point, but the subsequent records are Uncorrected. It may be a coincidence, but the problem occurs on the change of the hour.

Date    Time    Corr_Type
6/24/15 0:00    09:38:39am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:40:55am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:43:54am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:45:27am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:46:25am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:47:48am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:52:31am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:54:58am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:55:46am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:56:55am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    09:58:51am  Postprocessed Code
6/24/15 0:00    10:02:01am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:04:00am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:05:18am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:07:06am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:09:43am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:11:09am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:13:14am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:14:20am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:16:09am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:17:48am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:20:22am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:24:06am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:26:04am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:28:18am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:29:09am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:30:10am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:32:32am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:35:39am  Uncorrected
6/24/15 0:00    10:36:22am  Uncorrected

Date    Time    Corr_Type
6/25/15 0:00    10:45:50am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:48:38am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:49:44am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:51:03am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:52:34am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:53:29am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:56:40am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:58:28am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    10:59:48am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:00:36am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:03:00am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:03:45am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:05:49am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:08:05am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:12:59am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:14:52am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:16:38am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:17:28am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:18:26am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:19:37am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:21:10am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:26:08am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:29:17am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:32:36am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:40:47am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:45:14am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:48:17am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    11:58:18am  Postprocessed Code
6/25/15 0:00    12:04:29pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:06:28pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:09:01pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:10:57pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:13:51pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:16:23pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:17:29pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:18:47pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:20:37pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:24:01pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:25:01pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:26:10pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:27:45pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:29:23pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:32:55pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:34:59pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:38:38pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:40:29pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:42:14pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:44:05pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:47:16pm  Uncorrected
6/25/15 0:00    12:49:06pm  Uncorrected

I haven't noticed anything peculiar on the GPS receiver itself that might indicate a problem during data collection.

I've done the differential correction on the same day as when the data were collected, and also on subsequent dates, so I don't believe this is a CORS hourly vs. daily issue.

Anyone have an idea on what's causing this (and how to prevent it)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the positions which do not post-process are in similar GPS conditions to positions which do post-process (i.e. you are not randomly walking under trees every hour and standing in the open the rest of the time.)

In my experience (I use Trimble TerraSync and PathFinder Office post-processing at least once a week) the most likely cause of problems like this which occur on hour boundaries is some problem in the base data you use, not a data collector problem.  For example, a few minutes of data is missing at the start of the hour.

Things you could try:

- If you know what you are doing, look for missing epochs in the base
  data.
- Try post-processing using a different base station (preferably
  one which uses a GNSS receiver from a different manufacturer)
- If Pathfinder Office offers "Hourly" and "Daily" versions of the base
  station, try the "Daily" version (I assume you normally use the "Hourly"
  version if both are available.)

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected these types of errors before by making copies of the CORS base stations' properties, and changing the internet server property parameter "&duration=%LL%&" to "&duration=24&". This tells the service to download 24 hours worth of data, ensuring 100% coverage for processing. Otherwise I consistently get 24% coverage...

In Utilities > Differential Corrections > Base Provider Search > Select > 
then highlight the CORS station you want to use, and click "Copy". From there, go to "Internet Server" and change the Base File Address Format as above...